# Use a Java HttpSession variable in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, attributes, httpsession

I'm new to Java Web development. I read many post related to this problem, it have been discussed a lot... but I can't figure out how to make it work for me... So please be kind :o)

I have a simple form that I can submit. By default I want the form to display today's date.

Here is my servlets code snippet:

```
@WebServlet("/Main")
public class Main extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Main() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String date;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------\nBegin doGet");
        System.out.println("Date " + date);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        // Date - Get today date to fill the welcome form
        Date dNow = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
        date = (String) ft.format(dNow);
        session.setAttribute("date", date);

        // Go to main page
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/main.jsp").forward(request, response);
        System.out.println("\nEnd doGet\n-----------------------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------\nBegin Post Session");
        System.out.println("Date " + date);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/main.jsp").forward(request, response);
        System.out.println("\nEnd doPost\n-----------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

The trace in the eclipse console show the correct value.

But in my JSP I don't know how to display it. I tried

```
<p>${date}</p>
```

this one give a blank paragraph.
and

```
<%= session.getAttribute("date");%>
```

This one gives an execution error on the server side.

Can someone explain me what is wrong in my code? Not just a link on the forum which I've already read but not understood ;o)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access session attributes as follows in jsp pages,

Use `${sessionScope.date}` instead of `${date}` in `<p>` tag.

Make sure the jsp is allow access session by adding `<%@ page session="true" %>` at the top of the page.

Comment: Yes! <%@ page session="true" %> solve my problem :o) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A JSP expression doesn't use a **";"** to end the expression.  Instead of:

```
<%= session.getAttribute("date");%>
```

try

```
<%= session.getAttribute("date") %>
```

Also, servlets typically handle concurrent requests so it needs to be stateless.  Move `date` to be a local method variable instead of class variable so it's thread safe.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will do that